# HAProxy restrict single backend by ip range

Tags: ubuntu, backend, haproxy

I have inherited an HAProxy setup with around twenty backend definitions (and little else) in the config file. I have been asked to restrict one of the backends to a specific IP range, but so far my research (and limited HAProxy knowledge) have yielded nothing.

Whilst reading the [manual](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt), I have found a network_allowed parameter that would [work for a frontend](https://raymii.org/s/snippets/haproxy_restrict_specific_urls_to_specific_ip_addresses.html), but I don't seem to have any front end definitions and I don't want to apply this restriction to any of the other proxy routes. Is there anything I can specifically use on a backend to restrict access by IP range?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To have a functional HAProxy setup you would need either 'frontend' or 'listen' directives.  These are the only directives that will respond to incoming requests.  The 'backend' directive only provides for a way to route traffic behind the proxy.

That being said, here are the entries you need in a 'frontend' or 'listen' directive to accomplish your goals:

```
acl white_list src 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.10.0/24
tcp-request content accept if white_list
tcp-request content reject
```

These directives would allow only traffic coming from the 192.168.1/24 and 192.168.10/24 subnets.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `tcp-request connection` instead of `tcp-request content`?

Comment: in older versions there is no `tcp-request connection` v 1.4 in my case. `tcp-request content` works fine

Comment: @Jason Is it possible to apply this filter only on a specific Server Name Indication and if so, how do I do that ?

Comment: @SebMa Not directly, as far as i know.  You could have a primary frontend that handles the SNI, then does an internal redirect to another listening port which could then apply the whitelist ACL.  We do something similar at my company to handle TLS termination for some, but not all, managed URLs.  If you need a concrete example, start another question and comment back here.